# In what book and chapter is Olver introduced?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In what book and chapter is Olver introduced in "The Wheel of Time" series. I thought it was in "Lord of Chaos", or am I mistaken?

Comment: As per the [tour], you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. You'll even get some points for it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the first time he was introduced was indeed *[Lord of Chaos](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Lord_of_Chaos/Chapter_5)*, Chapter 5, "A Different Dance":

> Mat heads toward a disturbance in the street and finds a man shaking a little boy like a dog with a rat. It is a Hunter that is upset because the peasant boy sat on his horse. Mat disables him with the butt end of his spear and then when the Hunter's companion tries to draw his sword, disables him also. Edorion catches the boy and Mat notes that he is the ugliest boy he's ever seen. The boy's name is Olver and he is nine years old and horses like him. Estean comes up to Mat to announce a Sea Folk ship has come up the river. A Sea Folk wavemistress and her blademaster are aboard, but debark on the Andoran side of the river so Mat will not be able to find out what this is all about.

Relevant quote:

> "A gelding." The boy gave another jerk at Edorion's grip, and finding it had not loosened, put on a sulky face. "It was a gelding, and it would not have hurt me. Horses like me. I am not a *little boy*. I am nine. And my name is Olver, not *boy*."